# python turtle Name error: shape is not defined

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics, python-3.8, python-turtle

When I tried in Mac os with python 3.8.3
this code:

```py
from turtle import *
shape("turtle")
```

I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeeva\Desktop\Tanmay_new\python\pi\Draw_pi\draw_pi.pyw", line 2, in <module>
    shape("turtle")
NameError: name 'shape' is not defined
```

It looks like  python doesn't reconize shape.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried using shape=('turtle')

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but then it will set a variable called shape to the value of 'turtle'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if you have a file named *turtle.py* other than the module. Rename it and try again